# Weird white bar at the bottom of my page

Tags: html, css

My current goal is to make a template responsive. Its really annoying because the creator only used fixed lengths, but I'm ok with it.

But there's one thing that I don't understand! At the bottom is a white bar and I can't get rid of it.

Can you please help me with that issue? Here is the example: http://bruteforce.tv/wordpress/raid

Comment: Looks fine to me. `Please update your browser. You are using an out of date version of blah blah blah`. That's what it's supposed to say, right? :P

Comment: Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). You need to post your code here.

Comment: To find the answer to this (Alex found it), you just inspect the element, check it's size and then work up the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine if you change the calc on `#appwindow` to `100% - 52px` rather than `64px`

```
#appwindow.portalmode {
position: absolute!important;
top: 0px!important;
left: 0px!important;
margin: 0px!important;
display: block;
width: 100%;
overflow: visible;
height: calc(100% - 52px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It would work  when I didnt get a scrollbar from it.

Comment: Ah found the solution, it was the span#version thingy!